# Is there a way to generate a mnemonic recovery phrase for an account on a private Ethereum chain?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have created a private Ethereum chain (via a genesis.json file, etc.). I would like to be able to use Truffle's [HD Wallet Provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider), and I need a mnemonic recovery phrase to do so. Is there a way to set this up for accounts on a private Ethereum chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate an HD Wallet first you generate the mnemonic and then you generate the private key and address.

If you generated a private key by other means and you do not have a mnemonic, then it is almost impossible to find the mnemonic seed that will generate that private key.

You would have to brute force the algorithm PBKDF2, used by [bip39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#from-mnemonic-to-seed) to derive the seed from the mnemonic. In that case certainly it is much easier to generate a new HD Wallet.

Comment: Thanks, I had this in my head backwards. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a seed phrase is completely independent of where you're going to use it.